# How to view what version of gem is installed on heroku through bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I am not sure if I am missing anything here! How do I execute `bundle show GEM_NAME` for my heroku app?

I wanted to see what version of gem is installed on the running heroku application. I have messed up with my local bundle and now one of the gem is upgraded and its not backword compatible!

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Heroku Cedar, you can run:

```
$ heroku run bundle show GEM_NAME
```